# Query for non-BsonDocument object in Mongo with .Net Driver 2.0

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

How do I do I do a basic query of a POCO object from a Mongo database using the 2.0 driver? This seems like such a basic question, but all the [docs](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.0/getting_started/quick_tour/#find-all-documents-in-a-collection) on the Mongo site talk only about using BsonDocument. There is a [page](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.0/reference/bson/mapping/) that talks about mapping the BsonDocuments to standard C# classes, but the page does not show how to do queries that automatically deserialize into an object of a class other than BsonDocument. I would like to do something like this:

List<MyClass> documents = collection.Find<MyClass>().ToListAsync();

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Builders to create a filter to search for the objects. Builders/Filters are found in the MongoDB.Driver and MongoDB.Driver.Linq namespaces

For example:

```csharp
// Query by ID (ensure it's an object id)
SomeClass result = await _collection.Find(Builders<SomeClass>.Filter.Eq(i => i.Id, id)).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
return result;
```

There is also some good information on this page about the builders and definitions: http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.0/reference/driver/definitions/

Comment: Cool, that tells me how to deserialize the BSON into objects. What do we do if we want to return all of the items in the collection as SomeClass objects? Like the FindAll<SomeClass>() method in the old API.

Comment: Just use a blank BsonDocument() as the filter: `return await _collection.Find<SomeClass>(new BsonDocument()).ToListAsync();`